# Acumatica Adding processing page within tab

Tags: acumatica

Im trying to create a custom processing page within a tab of a custom page. Im working with a custom extension and have the DAC declared in my extension class.

Im unable to set the DataMember of my graph to my PXProcessing object

My processing BLC

`public class tableProcess: PXGraph<submittalProcess>
  {
         public PXCancel<PX.Objects.PM.ProjectEntry_Extension.ProjectLinesTable> Cancel;
       public PXProcessing<PX.Objects.PM.ProjectEntry_Extension.ProjectLinesTable, Where<PX.Objects.PM.ProjectEntry_Extension.ProjectLinesTable.contractID, Equal<Current<Contract.contractID>>>> fixtureItems;
       public submittalProcess()

       {
          fixtureItems.SetProcessCaption("Approve");
          fixtureItems.SetProcessAllCaption("Approve All");
          fixtureItems.SetProcessDelegate<ProjectCustom.submittal>(delegate(ProjectCustom.submittal graph, PX.Objects.PM.ProjectEntry_Extension.ProjectLinesTable items)
           {
            graph.Clear();
            graph.ApproveOrder(items, true);
           });
        } 
  }`

Main BLC delcaring actions

```
public class submittal: PXGraph<submittal,        ProjectEntry_Extension.atcProjectLinesTable>
 {
  public PXSelect<ProjectEntry_Extension.atcProjectLinesTable> Orders;
  public void ApproveOrder(ProjectEntry_Extension.atcProjectLinesTable    order, bool isMassProcess = false)
  {
  Orders.Current = order;

 Orders.Update(order);
 Persist();
if (isMassProcess)
{
PXProcessing.SetInfo(String.Format(
 "Order {0} has been successfully approved.", order.ItemNumber));
}
}


public PXAction<ProjectEntry_Extension.atcProjectLinesTable> Approve;
[PXProcessButton]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Approve")]
protected virtual IEnumerable approve(PXAdapter adapter)
{
foreach (ProjectEntry_Extension.atcProjectLinesTable order in    adapter.Get())
{
Actions.PressSave();
PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate()
{
submittal graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<submittal>();
graph.ApproveOrder(order);
});
yield return order;
}
}
```

Ive tried using their namespaces to assign tableProcess.fixtureItems to the grid but its out of its extension class scope.

Is there a way to initialize tableProcess in my ProjectEntry_Extension class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Acumatica doesn't allow creation of nested pages within tab of another page. In your case, it would be better to emulate the look and feel of a processing screen inside a tab by declaring selection column and Process/Process All buttons for the processing grid. To launch some process for selected or all records in the processing grid, use static `PXLongOperation.StartOperation` method as explained in the **Implementing Processing Operations** section of **T200** training course.